# Create divs using a for loop in jQuery and assign IDs to each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently creating divs using a for loop.

The problem is when I try to assign a unique id to every div element that is being created within the for loop.

I am getting closer but at the moment the count starts at 36 instead of being 1.

Thanks so much for you help!

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Intro Webpage!</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this is my script.js:

```
for(i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="div'+ (i++) +'" />');
});
}
```

Also, my css:

```
div {
width: 167px;
height: 167px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #ff0000;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `loop in side document.ready instead of putting document.ready in loop` also you may not need to increament `i` within loop body as it is `increamented` in loop signature. You can read more about document.ready **[here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div id="div'+ i +'" />');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

All the provided answers will do the job but if you want to make it faster, you can do it like this. Also, if you want the `div` id to start with 1, you should do `++i` instead of `i++`. `i++` doesn't make sense since that's being done by the `for loop` automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divsToAppend = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        divsToAppend += '<div id="div' + (++i) + '" />';        
    }
    $('body').append(divsToAppend);
});​​
```

Comment: You said it could make it faster. How?

Comment: The `append` method won't be executed each time the loop runs. It will be executed only once at the end. A couple of articles if you want to read [Article 1](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/), [Article 2](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html='';
    for(i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        html += '<div id="div'+ i +'" />';
    }
    $('body').append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the $(document).ready out of the loop for starters.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do loop here
}
```