# how can i create div using loop. i found this code in a book but it isnt working

Tags: javascript

This code is not creating a single div in the webpage which i linked the js below. how can i makes changes in the js or html for the code to be executed as expected

```
var div,
  container = document.getElementById("container");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  div = document.createElement("div");
  div.onclick = function () {
    alert("This is box #" + i);
  };
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: This is working as expected, but the div is empty/unstyled so you can't see it

Comment: Right-click on the page and select "Inspect". In there, in the DOM, you can see the empty divs.

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with the container id ? You can check it.

Comment: You can refer to a similar solution in jquery here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13814075/16327700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** To show a `div` you have to include some text inside `div`tag

**2)** You should use `let` instead of `var` to get the correct number when user click on `div`

```js
var div,
  container = document.getElementById("container");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // change -> let instead of var
  div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = `div${i}` // change -> add some text
  div.onclick = function() {
    alert("This is box #" + i);
  };
  container.appendChild(div);

}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You don't have to add text, you could just as easily style it with height/width.

Comment: I agree, but after looking at the OP code the missing part is the text not the styles. 